# Read/Write to file using void pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, fwrite

As part of a college assignment, I'm trying to do a simple C app, using Win32 for GUI programming and writing my own dynamic linked list for storing data. Since i could use it for other things later, I'm trying to write a generic list, with "built in" functions for reading and writing data to a file. Now here's my problem

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 typedef struct tagA{
     int t_int;
     float t_float;
     char t_char;
     char t_vchar[30];
 } A;

 typedef struct tagB{
     void *data;
     struct tagB *prox;
 } B;

 int main(){
     A dA = {1, 1.5, 'a', "teste123"};
     B dB = {&dA, NULL};
     dB.data = &dA;
     B dB2 = {0};

     FILE *fp;
     fp = fopen("Data.txt", "w");

     size_t dSize = sizeof(dA);
     printf("Struct size: %d", dSize);

     if(fp == NULL){
         printf("nope");
     }else{
         fwrite(&dB.data, dSize, 1, fp);
     }
     fclose(fp);
     fp = fopen("Data.txt", "r");

     dB2.data = malloc(dSize);
     fread(&dB2.data, dSize, 1, fp);

     printf("\n\n%s", ((A*)dB2.data)->t_vchar);
 }
```

This is the code I'm trying to work out.

- The writing works just fine, and I just have to make it to a separate function that receives the pointer to the data struct and its size.
- But the reading is off... Once read and printed to the console, the t_int shows a really large number, the t_float has nothing, and so the char and string...

Also, I know its not the best written, most efficient and safe code, but it's just a prototype, something that came into my mind...

Comment: `fwrite(dB.data, dSize, 1, fp);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are writing the *address of* `&dB.data` with `fwrite` instead of `dB.data` itself (it is already a pointer). For example:

```
fwrite(dB.data, dSize, 1, fp);
```

will resolve your problem (with the like corresponding change to `fread`).

Comment: Well, my bad... Im still not used to pointers and stuff... All works well now, thank you!

Comment: @MathiasHemmer - also, be careful when mixing nodes declared with *automatic storage* and those with *allocated storage*. While there is nothing wrong with declaring `B` with *automatic storage*, you should allocate all nodes for the list (you can use a temporary node with automatic storage to fill and copy to the node that will live in your list). Otherwise, later if you attempt to iterate of your list freeing nodes, you are in trouble if you have included one with automatic storage.

Comment: Well, since this is intended for dynamic storage , there is not going to be a single node automaticly placed in the list, thank you for pointing that out though

Answer (score 0):

> `void *data;`

It's not useful to declare `data` as `void*`. Declare it as `A *data;` instead.

> `fwrite(&dB.data, dSize, 1, fp);`
>      `...`
>      `fread(&dB2.data, dSize, 1, fp);`

`dB2.data` is a pointer, just use `dB2.data`. See example below. For better readability you can declare `ptr_data` instead of `data`

```
typedef struct tagA {
    int t_int;
    float t_float;
    char t_char;
    char t_vchar[30];
} A;

typedef struct tagB {
    A *data;
    struct tagB *prox;
} B;

int main() {
    A dA = { 1, 1.5, 'a', "teste123" };
    B dB = { 0 };
    dB.data = &dA;
    B dB2 = { 0 };

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("Data.txt", "w");

    size_t dSize = sizeof(dA);
    printf("Struct size: %d", dSize);

    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("nope");
    }
    else {
        fwrite(dB.data, dSize, 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("Data.txt", "r");

    dB2.data = malloc(dSize);
    fread(dB2.data, dSize, 1, fp);

    printf("\n\n%s\n", dB2.data->t_vchar);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, im aware I could use just a pointer to the struct itself, but this is intended to not know what kind of struct it's working one.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is at `fwrite()`, `fread()`. The first param of them is the pointer which points at the real data you want to write/read.
Since you want to read/write a `struct A`, the pointer must actually point at `struct A`, not `struct A*`.

Just replace

```
fwrite(&dB.data, dSize, 1, fp);
fread(&dB2.data, dSize, 1, fp);
```

with

```
fwrite(dB.data, dSize, 1, fp);
fread(dB2.data, dSize, 1, fp);
```